# How to change max/min jdbc connections of akka-persistence-jdbc?

Tags: scala, jdbc, akka, lagom

I am trying to change the minimum and maximum pool size of JDBC connections used by `akka-persistence-jdbc`.

I tried to change the following in my `application.conf`:

```
jdbc-journal {
  slick.db.maxConnections = 2
  slick.db.minConnections = 2
}

jdbc-snapshot-store {
  slick.db.maxConnections = 2
  slick.db.minConnections = 2
}

jdbc-read-journal {
  slick.db.maxConnections = 2
  slick.db.minConnections = 2
}
```

But it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually the solution is to change `Lagom` related configuration:

```
db.default {
  async-executor {
    numThreads = 2
    minConnections = 2
    maxConnections = 2
  }
}
```